# OCS 2007 R2 Client not syncing Address book

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I've checked online for most solution for this issue, but nothing seems to be working. When I check the log files on our OCS 2007 R2 server, it is identifying 25 users in the address book. However, when I try and force a sync with the clients, they do not update. I can find the users if I search for them, but they are not coming down by themselves.

Is there anything I can check or force from the client side? There is no address book file locally to delete and re-force down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a minsunderstanding, the process was working properly. To add the users to a Communicator in your environment, you need to run the following scripts:

```
CScript LCSAddContacts.wsf /usersfile:contacts.txt /contactsfile:contacts.txt /contactsgroup:Office

CScript LCSAddACEs.wsf /usersfile:contacts.txt /acesfile:aces.txt
```

The first script adds all of the users in the contacts.txt file to all of the users listed in the contacts.txt file (you can use 2 separate files. I just used 1 for simplicity, and I wanted everyone to have everyone else).

The second script is used to set permissions. It is so no one has to ask anyone else for permission to add them or write to them.

Here's a sample of how contacts.txt looks:

```
sip:Bob.Smith@breedlove.local
sip:Steve.Franks@breedlove.local
```

And a sample of how aces.txt looks:

```
sip:Bob.Smith@breedlove.local Allow Allow
sip:Steve.Franks@breedlove.local Allow Allow
```

Answer (score 0):

The GAL client copy is stored by default in:
\Documents and Settings\UID\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Communicator

You can force a refresh by exiting Communicator, deleting that file, then restarting Communicator.  This should be logged in the client computer's Application event log.  However (from memory) the address book is only generated on the OCS server every 24 hours so you may need to check for issues there too.  There may be a connectivity issue with Exchange.

Comment: I found the GALContacts.db file, deleted it, and restarted communicator. However, it still only downloaded the contact I had manually entered. How can I troubleshoot where the issue is?

Comment: It seems the DB may be the issue. When I run abserver.exe -validatedb I get the following error at the end:

Exception occurred while validating database.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception type: NullReferenceException

Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas there. I agree it sounds like a possible DB issue. Any insight in Technet? There are also a couple of third party OCS support sites that might have knowledgebases or forums for this question.